# Is it possible to sort the contents of the "All Programs" portion of the Start Menu?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, start-menu

I know it's possible to do this in the classic start menu, but wanted to know if the same could be done in the regular start menu.

Comment: Which version of Windows? Do you want to do custom sorting?

Comment: Vista/7 = Always sorted..(not the OS, the menu)

XP, don't you just right-click and select "Sort by Name"?

Comment: In my experience, Vista/7 allow custom sorting, then resets itself at next boot. I'm interested to see an answer to this, as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but "Enable dragging and dropping" must be checked/enabled.

In Windows XP: right-click the Start menu/Properties/"Start menu", press Customize/tab Advanced/check "Enable dragging and dropping"/OK/OK.

Now it is possible to sort by right-clicking on any item in "All Programs" and select "Sort" in the context menu.

(I have checked it on Windows XP, but not on Windows Vista or Windows 7. Please correct me if it does not work on those two platforms.)

Comment: +1 Nice, didn't know that a menu can have a context menu :-). BTW, the procedure described for Windows XP also works on Window Server 2003.